# Req.user coming as undefined but works fine while sending the same post request through Postman app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js

When I send a post request through fetch to my node server it successfully serializes the user but req.user comes out as undefined. But it works fine while testing in Postman

I tried including credential:'include' in fetch request. Then an error stating "Failed to load http://localhost:4444/login: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access."  comes out.

I included

```
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: "http://localhost:3000/sign-in"
  })
);
```

But the cross origin request still persists

Here is the code for my fetch req

```
fetch("http://localhost:4444/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      credentials: "include",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password
      })
    })
```

Comment: 1. Make sure that you have mounted `cors()` middleware _BEFORE_ you have mounted your routes. 
2. Try either `origin: "http://localhost:3000/"` or `origin: [ 'http://localhost:3000' ]` as options

Comment: @AnandUndavia  Same error. I have used this code.                             
  app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000"]
  })
);

Comment: Try including `http` or `https` in your `origin` array. Or try using a callback function as origin: `origin: (origin, callback) => callback(true, null)`